# how do i compile this boolean statement

Tags: string, boolean

I'm writing in java and cannot for the life of me figure out how to compile one block, i need to
print out an author name, title and boolean condition but it just won't compile no matter what i try, i am getting errors such as ')' expected, or "not a statement" the code in question is below,
i am going to be doing an if else statement for it but firstly just want to figure how to compile the statement:

```
     System.out.println("Title: " + title + " , Author: " + author + " (available)";
```

i have tried spaces in all kinds of places, parathesis, speech marks so probably the only thing i havent tried is the actual solution,

any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In you code the closing `)` is missing. Also in you code the boolean is not converted to String. I would advise to use `String.valueOf()`.

Try

```
System.out.println("Title: " + title + " , Author: " + author + ", available: " + String.valueOf(available));
```